# Usage of "or rather"

Tags: grammar

A friend asked yesterday how to diagram these two phrases within a longer sentence:

"... in a mansion, or rather in a shed ..."

we're wondering what function "or rather" serves?

thanks!

Comment: Please include a full sentence and context. Otherwise, it would not be easy to get a good answer. Also, please include your own research on the word. Thanks.

Comment: It is basically saying: "in a mansion, or instead a shed."

Comment: As a sentence fragment, it is difficult, but it sounds like "rather" is proceeding correction.  "This comment deserves an upvore, or, rather, ten" :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is a conjunction between two prepositional phrases‚ specifically, it is a conjunctive adverbial phrase designed to connect one prepositional phase with a second prepositional phase that modifies or clarifies the first prepositional phase. Other examples of conjunctive adverbial phrases include "so that," "in addition," and "on the other hand," each of which, of course, serves its own particular purpose.

Comment: This is possible.  For instance, in a  context like "I could live in a mansion, a town home, or in a shed."  But in a different context like "call it spare accommodations, or rather a shed," the phrase between commas is an appositive (*shed* renaming *spare accommodations*) or an aside or a combination of the two.  In the latter, *rather* is an idiom meaning "called in other words."  The fragment from the OP doesn't really fit either pattern, so we need more context.

Comment: @deadrat I don't get it. You're saying that "or rather" means "called in other words"? "Shed" is not another word for "accommodations" or "mansion." Shed clearly is a refinement, a modification, even a rewording. It is a corrective to what has already been said, and, yes, "or rather" is an idiom, but its function as an adjectival connector is recognized in every one of the several dictionaries I've checked, no additional context needed.

Comment: No, I'm taking no position on what it means.  I can't tell from the fragment, notwithstanding what every dictionary says.  Partly it's because *shed* is not a refinement of *mansion*.  It's the other way around:  "I live in a shed, but I'd rather live in a mansion."  But even this doesn't match the fragment.  I need to know what verb *rather* modifes.

Answer (score 0):

*Shed* is not a kind of *mansion*, so calling it a correction or refinement is unjustified. Hence, in this case, *or rather* is a correction. It isn't a mansion; it's a shed. Note the comment under "Or rather" at

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/rather